# Dose contracts must be deployed?

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs, cpp-ethereum

I see js programmers compile and call solidity contract without actually deploying it using hardhat and/or similar tools. Do they really can use the contract without deploying on the chain(like swap on uni-swap for real) or it's just test(not real transaction) on local machine. Sorry for my question I'm new to Ethereum dev and i don't know js at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it is not possible to communicate with UniSwap on the main network without deployment on the main network, because we have access to the information and functions on the chain in the smart contract.We cannot, for example, deploy the contract on Polygon and expect to communicate with Ethereum network smart contracts, what you have seen was probably a test on the local network.

Comment: Ok.... thanks very much bro

Comment: hello brother one more question..... 1inch api end "quote", provides best price using different dexs. How to only fetch prices from polygone network? because I planned to deploy my contract on polygone chain because it is very cheap for beginner to practice.

Comment: You must use the Polygon Chain ID, which is 137, for example, for Ethereum, if you used this link: https://api.1inch.exchange/v3.0/1/quote, replace 137 instead of one.

Comment: https://api.1inch.exchange/v3.0/137/quote  ... like this right?

Comment: Yes, I may have sent the link wrongly. In the link you are using, just use 137 instead of 1

Comment: thanks very much bro ...